# How to check if date in a cell is in current month

Tags: excel, vba, date

I'm trying to write an excel vba where the code will check for each row, if the DATE cell is in the current month or not.

Example: excel cell = 01-01-2021 --> check if month = currentmonth (01) -> if yes, OK

This is the code I have, it doesn't give errors but doesn't give results either (ignores the correct dates as if it's not correct):

```
            For i = 2 To LastRow1
                'check if effective date = current month
                If Month(.Cells(i, 17)) = Month(Now()) Then
                    'check if more than 5 days since initiated
                    If .Cells(i, 21).Value > 5 Then
                        If .Cells(i, 11) = "Onboarding" Then
                            LastRow2 = Sh2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1
                    
                            'copy email 'awaiting person'
                            .Cells(i, 32).Copy Sh2.Range("A" & LastRow2)
```

I googled around a bunch, and found Month(Now()) to get the current month in a numeric value, but cells(i, 17) where the date is (01-01-2021 for instance) doesn't get seen as matching, even though it is.

Comment: `month(cells(i, 17))`

Comment: `Month` returns the month number, so `.Cells(i, 17) = Month(Now())` would be equivalent to `.Cells(i, 17) = 1`...

Comment: @Warcupine changing it to "If Month(Sh1.Cells(i, 17)) = Month(Now()) Then" gives error 424 Object required :(

Comment: Because `Sh1` is not `Set`

Comment: @BigBen I actually have this set earlier in the code: Set Sh1 = WB1.Sheets(1)

Comment: It's not clear why you're attempting to use `Sh1` where your original code snippet has `.Cells(i, 17)`. That said, just comparing the month number is not sufficient; you would also need to compare the year.

Comment: @BigBen I don't need the year though, only the month is needed, no matter if it's from 2020, 2021 or 1993

Comment: Ok.. then it's still not clear why you're trying to use `Sh1`. Please [edit] your question with your latest code.

Comment: @BigBen I tried it both with Sh1 and without, but error remains. I've updated the code now with Warcupine's initial suggestion

Comment: What is the `With...` statement that `.Cells(i, 17)` is referring to?

Comment: With Activesheet

Comment: You should probably test if the value in a cell is a date using `IsDate`.

Comment: Month(CDate(.Cells(i, 17))) would force it to be interpreted as a date